# Why Android Studio can't find resource?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, resources

I followed this tutorial: http://imperialsoup.com/2016/04/29/simple-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract-tutorial/
And I have problem with png image:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. chnage `tools:context="com.test.ocr.ocrtest.MainAcivity"`
2. remove / from `android:src="@drawable/test_image"`

Comment: @AndyD please post your updated screenshot after making this change

Comment: It works now - I had to remove .png from android:src

Comment: @AndyD Happy to help you.

Answer (score 2):

delete

```
tools:context=".MainAcivity"
```

And the source path should be like this

```
android:src="@drawable/test_image"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use next code sample to resolve problem:

```
tools:context=".MainAcivity"
should correct as
tools:context="com.example.Acountname.ProjectName.MainActivity"
(find your package name & include before ".MainActivity")

android:src="@/drawable/test_image"
should correct as
android:src="@drawable/test_image"
(remove "/" from "@/drawable")
```